# MySQL join on record that might not exist

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm trying to execute a query that looks similar to this:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.table1_id
WHERE table3.column1 != 'foo' AND <other_conditions>
LIMIT 1;
```

The thing is--I want the query to return a result regardless of whether the record in `table3` exists or not. That is--if the record in `table3` is present, I want to check whether that record has a certain column value. If the record in `table3` *doesn't* exist, I want the query to assume that the condition is TRUE.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use a left join on the table. If no corresponding record exists, the value from the table will be null, so you can use coalesce to get a value that you can compare to the string:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.table1_id
WHERE COALESCE(table3.column1, '') != 'foo' AND <other_conditions>
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Perfect. The `COALESCE` was the final trigger. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've come to a point where you noticed that there is a difference between WHERE conditions and JOIN conditions.

```
SELECT 
  <columns> 
FROM
  table1 
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
  LEFT  JOIN table3 ON table3.table1_id = table1.id AND table3.column1 <> 'foo' 
WHERE
  <other_conditions>
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer put me on the right track, but didn't take into account the fact that if `table3.column1` was `'foo'`, the query would return the result anyway.

Comment: @vonconrad: That's not the case. This joins against a sub-set of `table3` that does not even contain `column1 = 'foo'`. There is no way that these rows can show up in the result.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried it several times and it doesn't work. Because the `LEFT JOIN` conditions evaluate to false (the last one will be false, as `table3.column1 = 'foo'`), the `LEFT JOIN` will be excluded from the resultset as if there were no matching rows; the resultset will be complete. Now, this won't work for me as I *only* want a resultset if `table3.column1` isn't `'foo'` or the record in `table3` doesn't exist.

Comment: @vonconrad: Oh, I see. That's a misunderstanding on my end, you are of course correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an outer join to include table3 instead of an inner join.